# How to specify context of translation in Django {% trans %} {% blocktrans %}?

Tags: django, internationalization, django-templates, django-i18n

[Documentation of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/)  says *Contextual markers are also supported by the trans and blocktrans template tags.* but it not explained how to do it?

Can you help marking translation context since I have some words with several meanings.

In Python I can do in such way:

```
pgettext("month name", "May")
pgettext("verb", "May")
```

**How to specify translation context in Django template?**

```
{% blocktrans %}May{% endblocktrans %}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is explained at the very end of their specific paragraphs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag

> `{% trans %}` also supports contextual markers using the context keyword:
>
> ```
> {% trans "May" context "month name" %}
> ```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag

> `{% blocktrans %}` also supports contextual markers using the context keyword:
>
> ```
> {% blocktrans with name=user.username context "greeting" %}Hi {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
{% blocktrans context "month name" %}May{% endblocktrans %}
```